# Xcodebuild run application unit tests in different languages

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, testing, xcodebuild

Here was described that it should be possible to overwrite user defaults settings using the xcodebuild command.

I also need to use this mechanism to set the language to a specific one for executing my unit tests. Any Idea how to accomplish this? The xcodebuild command always fails launching the simulator when I pass '-AppleLanguages="(en)"' with an exception:

```
2015-09-08 13:07:13.178 xcodebuild[82720:7171617] -[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2945442d65642875
** INTERNAL ERROR: Uncaught exception **
Exception: -[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2945442d65642875
Stack:
  0  0x00007fff8edfe024 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff97d8776e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x00007fff8ee010ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
  3  0x00007fff8ed46e24 ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff8ed46998 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x00007fff982941f2 __CopyAppleLanguages_block_invoke (in Metadata)
  6  0x00007fff98331c13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7  0x00007fff98331b26 dispatch_once_f (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8  0x00007fff982941a8 CopyAppleLanguages (in Metadata)
  9  0x00007fff98293f0e _MDAccessCopyClientPort (in Metadata)
 10  0x00007fff9829befe ___MDQueryMakeClientPortLocked_block_invoke (in Metadata)
 11  0x00007fff98336323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
 12  0x00007fff98331c13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 13  0x00007fff9833488f _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 14  0x00007fff98342fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 15  0x00007fff9a6bca9d _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 16  0x00007fff9a6ba3dd start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

[1]    82720 abort      xcodebuild -workspace APP.xcworkspace -scheme APP_DEBUG -sdk  test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man xcodebuild` reveals two options for doing that : `-testLanguage` and `-testRegion` which follows the ISO 639-1 and ISO 3166-1 standards